# Regex works in regexer but returning nothing in php preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Using regexr.com my regex is working but preg_match in php returns null.

Tried many times in several php testers.

Regex is:

```
/Donor Comment:\*(.*?)\*/
```

Text is:

```
United States* > Donor Comment:*Thx Barbara for your wonderful offerings, and thx to > CVRAN for the essential support you provide to asylum seekers and for > the creative fundraising via an Arts Marathon!*
```

Works in Regexr

PHP is:

```
preg_match('/Donor Comment:\*(.*?)\*/', $msg, $donor_comment);
```

Preg_match returns null

Comment: It works for me: https://ideone.com/j5Qv8y

Comment: Is it possible `$msg` contains newlines in the text? If so, use the `s` flag in the regexp to allow `.` to match newline.

Comment: Booya! That worked, thank you so much, spent whole day yesterday hitting my head against a wall thinking it was a stupid error in my code.